# I am not getting result from php function that is json encoded

Tags: posts, wpdb, array

So I am trying to build an array of post data. But when I json encoded it I am not getting back the post object data from the database.

Here are my two functions

```
public function get_post_from_url(){
    global $wpdb;
    $postid = url_to_postid(esc_url("http://localhost/teln/web-security-privacy-not-trade-off-both-should-be-goal-engineers-say/"));
    $query = "
    SELECT      ID, post_date, post_title, post_excerpt, post_type
    FROM        $wpdb->posts
    WHERE       $wpdb->posts.ID = %d
    AND         $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    LIMIT       1
    ";
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($query, $postid);
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    return $results;

}


public function process_post_data_and_return_json($results){
    $to_return = array();
    $post_date = get_the_date( "U", $results[0]->ID );
    $tags      = get_the_tags( $results[0]->ID );
    $main_tag  = "";
    if ( is_array( $tags ) ) {
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            if ( $tag->slug == 'featured' ) {
                $main_tag = 'Featured';
            } else if ( $tag->slug == 'highlight' ) {
                $main_tag = 'Highlight';
            }
        }
    }

    $to_return['tag']           = $main_tag;
    $to_return['ID']            = $results[0]->ID;
    $to_return['date']          = date( "M j, Y", $post_date );
    $to_return['hour']          = date( "H:i", $post_date );
    $to_return['post_title']    = $results[0]->post_title;
    $to_return['post_excerpt']  = ( ! empty( $results[0]->post_excerpt ) ? "<span class='bbna-email-excerpt'>" . $results[0]->post_excerpt . "</span>" : "<span class='no-excerpt-warning'>NO EXCERPT FOUND!</span>" );

    $response = json_encode($to_return);

    return $response;
}
```

When I print_r these functions this is what I receive:

for the first function this is the result

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 85332 [post_date] => 2015-05-27 06:01:38 [post_title] => Web Security, Privacy Not Trade-Off, Both Should Be Goal, Engineers Say [post_excerpt] => Building trust in the Internet requires a concerted effort to bolster security and user privacy, technical policy panelists said May 25 at an International Telecommunication Union event in Geneva. [post_type] => post ) )
```

For the second function this is the result:

```
{"tag":"","ID":null,"date":"Jan 1, 1970","hour":"00:00","post_title":null,"post_excerpt":"NO EXCERPT FOUND!<\/span>"}
```

Comment: how are you passing the output from the first function to the second? also, why not just use an API function to get the post rather than custom SQL? using prepare is unnecessary because the result can't be injected.

Comment: Your URL is hard-coded. Why are you using a resource heavy function like `url_to_postid()`?